# Best practice for keeping VMWare Workstation templates up-to-date with Windows Update

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-update

I have occasional projects (once every 2-3 months) which I start by creating a VMware VM from a template.  I am running VMware Workstation 9.0, nothing fancy like vSphere so VMware Update Manager not an option for me.  Just a single developer on the ~US$200 version of VMware.

The problem is that when I create the new VM, I spend about an hour downloading updates from WU.  Question is - what is the best practice for keeping these templates up to date?  One approach I've considered is this, let me know if anyone sees a better way:

1. Create new VM by doing a Full Clone from template.
2. Run WU and update it.  Rinse and repeat.  reboot, reboot, reboot. :)
3. Once all updates are applied, create a new VM template from this updated one.
4. Delete the old template.

This at least means I'm starting from 2-3 months ago instead of 6-8 months ago when I create a new VM.  Is there a better way?  Should I occasionally boot the template VMs themselves (can you even do that?) and update them in place?

Thanks for any tips on doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates might not be the best solution for you given the frequency of which they are used. You might be better off maintaining an image in [WDS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj648426.aspx).

You can add updates directly to the image with `dism`. The whole process can be [scripted with PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrdogs/archive/2012/02/15/applying-windows-updates-to-a-base-wim-using-dism-and-powershell.aspx).

> **Manual installation**
>
> Firstly, locate your most up to date image and make a copy of it. This
>   is so we can stream the newest Windows Updates into the mounted WIM
>   without risk of damaging a working WIM. I suggest copying the WIM to a
>   temp location. Also, put the Windows Update that you want to apply
>   into an Updates folder.
>
> Next, mount your image in the temp location.
>
> ```
> DISM /Mount-Wim /WimFile:C:\TempMount\install.wim /index:1 /Mountdir:C:\TempMount\Mount
> ```
>
> Now inject the Windows Update you need to apply
>
> ```
> DISM /image:C:\TempMount\Mount /Add-Package /Packagepath:C:\Updates\
> ```
>
> Finally, save an unmount the image
>
> ```
> DISM /Unmount-Wim /Mountdir:C:\TempMount\Mount /commit DISM /Cleanup-Wim
> ```
>
> **Automating the installation**
>
> While running updates manually like this is an easy way to apply a few
>   updates, hundreds of updates require more work. Here’s how you would
>   apply the updates using PowerShell.
>
> ```
> $UpdatesPath = "C:\Updates\*" 
> $MountPath = “C:\TempMount\Mount”
> $WimFile = “C:\TempMount\install.wim” 
> DISM \Mount-Wim /WimFile:$WimFile /index:1 /Mountdir:$MountPath 
> $UpdateArray = Get-Item $UpdatesPath 
> ForEach ($Updates in $UpdateArray) 
> { 
> DISM /image:$MountPath /Add-Package /Packagepath:$Updates 
> Start-Sleep –s 10
> } 
> Write-Host "Updates Applied to WIM" 
> DISM /Unmount-Wim /Mountdir:$MountPath /commit 
> DISM /Cleanup-Wim
> ```

Comment: I don't have a deep understanding of WDS but how is it any different than using a VM template? Can you inject updates into a WDS image? If not, then you've got to take the same steps as with a VM template to update the image and then recapture it, no?

Comment: You can [add updates directly to the image](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrdogs/archive/2012/02/15/applying-windows-updates-to-a-base-wim-using-dism-and-powershell.aspx) with `dism`. The link shows how it can be automated with PowerShell.

Comment: Just added all that mess to the answer (for preservation.) *Upvotez plox.*